# How do I join two tables on multiple columns when number of columns is unknown (pyspark)

Tags: sql, join, pyspark

Suppose I have two tables A and B. Let their structure be something like:

`A`:

```
------------------------------
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_4
------------------------------
   1  |  A    |  a    |  i
   2  |  B    |  b    |  ii
   3  |  C    |  c    |  iii
   4  |  D    |  d    |  iv
   5  |  E    |  e    |  v
------------------------------
```

`B`:

```
---------------
col_1 | col_3 
---------------
  1   |  null
  3   |  c
  null|  b
  2   |  null
--------------
```

It is sure that the column names in B are the same as in A, and I want to join them using an `OR` condition among various columns. The only catch is that the number of columns in B are not known.

How can I perform the join?

The pseudo code of what I want to do would look like:

```sql
select *
from A
join B
on A.col_1 == B.col_1
OR A.col_2 == B.col_2
......
OR A.col_k == B.col_k   --where k is the total number of columns in B
```

I had created the following string for `spark.sql`, but I was looking at a more `Pyspark-ic` way of doing it :

```py
sql_query = 'select s.* from dfA s join dfB on '

#join using or conditions
for i in dfB.columns:
    sql_query += 'dfA.' +i + ' == dfB.' + i + ' OR '

#remove the last extra 'OR'
sql_query = sql_query[:-3]

spark.sql(sql_query)
```

The above approach requires temp views to be created so that they can be accessed in the `sqlContext`.

Comment: How can the number of columns in a table not be known?  In any case, SQL as a general rule does not have any syntax for a variable number of columns in a `join` condition.

Comment: B is being auto generated using some logic. I want to iterate over all columns in B, if possible. The above has been implemented in Pyspark.

Comment: What I meant is, the number of columns in B can only be determined at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dataframe.columns](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns) returns the list of columns of a dataframe. With this property we can get the columns that are common to both dataframes:

```python
dfA = ...
dfB = ...

#get the common columns
common_cols = [col for col in dfA.columns if col in dfB.columns]

#create a list of join conditions
join_conds = [dfA[col].eqNullSafe(dfB[col]) for col in common_cols]

#combine all join conditions with "or"
cond = join_conds[0]
for c in join_conds[1:]:
    cond = cond | c

#use the combined condition in a join
dfA.join(dfB, cond).show()
```

Comment: @ghost . . . A dataframes approach is probably the best solution.

Comment: @werner, I added the approach I had followed. This is precisely the answer I was looking for.